# How to execute PendingIntent manually?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I show a notification and user navigates to a certain fragment when clicked on that notification.

```
fun showNotification() {
    val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(this)
        .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
        .setDestination(R.id.fragment)
        .createPendingIntent()
    ...
}
```

It does navigate correctly. However before navigating, I also want to check whether the user is logged in or not. The problem is that I can't check it because pendingIntent gets triggered as soon as I click on the notification. Is there a way for me to control before it gets executed?

I want something like this

```
if (isLoggedIn) pendingIntent.execute()
else navigateToLoginPage()
```

I tried overriding onNewIntent function however it didn't trigger at all.

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct but your logic is not.
you have to navigate your user to an auth fragment in both cases.

and then if the user is logged in you can navigate him/her to his own home fragment or where ever u want, but if he/she is not logged it you can notify him/her

Comment: But pending intent would already be executed by the time I navigated to the auth fragment. Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: Pendint intent just opens the application and navigates user to the activity that you are giving to the pendingIntent, first you bring your user inside your application using pending intent, then u play your logic that if he is logged in or not and after that you'll notify him what to do now

Comment: All I mean is that dont check if user is logged in and then decide to navigate, you will navigate him first to second fragment which is called auth fragment, if he is logged in, navigate to R.id.fragment and if not navigate to login fragment